# How to find K nearest neighbours from a dataframe of vectors

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I have a dataframe called `neighbours_lookup` with a column of IDs and a column with normalised data ('vec') stored as arrays:

```
    id  vec
0   857827315   [-0.5345224838248487, -0.5345224838248487, 1.8...
1   857827311   [-0.3535533905932738, -0.3535533905932738, 2.8...
2   857827316   [-0.3535533905932738, -0.3535533905932738, -0....
3   857827312   [-0.5345224838248487, 1.8708286933869707, -0.5...
4   857827313   [-0.35355339059327373, -0.35355339059327373, -...
```

I would like to write a function where I can input an ID and get the 10 nearest neighbours back.

I've looked at `skikit.neighbours` and I think that looks relevant - however, I can't work out how to use it. I've tried

```
knn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=10,
                       algorithm='auto')
for row in neighbours_lookup['vec']:
    knn.fit(row.reshape(1, -1))
```

And the error I get is

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

Please can someone explain where I should go from here? My dataframe will have >100,000 rows so I need it to be fast.

**---EDIT---**

Thanks to Darth Baba and my own messing around I have made it work! Function below.

```py
def get_k_neighbours(isbn,df,number_of_neighbours):

  def get_knn(df):
    vector_arrays = df['vec'].to_numpy().tolist()
    return NearestNeighbors().fit(vector_arrays)        

  def get_vector(df, isbn):
    return df.loc[df['isbn'] == isbn, 'vec'].iloc[0].reshape(1, -1)

  def flatten_neighbour_list(nb_indexes):
    nb_list = nb_indexes.tolist()
    return [item for sublist in nb_list for item in sublist]        

    knn = get_knn(df)
    vector = get_vector(df, isbn)
    nb_indexes = knn.kneighbors(vector,number_of_neighbours,return_distance=False)
    nb_indexes = flatten_neighbour_list(nb_indexes)
    return nb_indexes
```

Comment: Why are you reshaping it to (-1,1) ?

Comment: I had to do that earlier to make it work - I don't know!

Answer (score 1):

Numpy ndarray has an attribute reshape and not list hence the AttributeError. You can fit list of lists of shape (n_samples,n_features) to NearestNeighbors.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

knn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=10, algorithm='auto')
knn.fit(neighbours_lookup['vec'].to_numpy())

def get_neighbors(id):
    vector = neighbours_lookup.loc[id]
    return knn.kneighbors([vector], 10, return_distance=False)
```

Comment: Thanks - when I try that, I now get ```ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.```?

Comment: Try this updated answer change vector to [vector]